# chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().VARIABLE is undefined when using typescript, but works fine with javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a popup and background script. I was using the background script to store some variables and functions and was using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().VARIABLENAME to access them. I recently changed my chrome extension to typescript and now all those variables are undefined.

#### popup

```
let app = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().app 
console.log(app) // undefined, but used to print 1234
```

#### background

```
var app = "1234"
```

Comment: Your TS compiler probably converts `var` to `let` which prevents the variable from being accessible in another lexical scope. Another possibility is that the compiler wraps the entire code in an IIFE. There may be a way to configure the compiler but the simplest solution is to use `window.app = "1234"`.

Comment: works great! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to woxxom's suggestions this fixed it

#### popup

```
let app = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().app 
console.log(app) // 1234
```

#### background

```
var app = "1234"
window.app = app
```